# Find the Largest Distance between nodes of a Tree ? Can someone explain me the approach for this

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

[**Link to problem**](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/largest-distance-between-nodes-of-a-tree/)
**InterviewBit solution to the problem**

```
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A)
{
   vector<int> hgt(A.size(),0);
   int ans=0,maxx=0;
   for(int i=A.size()-1;i>0;i--)
   {
       ans=max(ans,hgt[A[i]]+hgt[i]+1);
       hgt[A[i]]=max(hgt[i]+1,hgt[A[i]]);
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Can someone explain to me the above code as well as their approach where they said as follows :

1. Pick any node u.
2. Find the node which is farthest from u, call it x.
3. Find the node which is farthest from x, call it q.
4. The answer will be the length of a path from x to q.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: Your code seems incorrect, please quote the true one.

Comment: @CiaPan I have edited the above code. The above code has been taken from InterviewBit's complete solution tab. This one was said to be the fastest.

Comment: You didn't specify what the `A` vector contains. And the code seems to rely on a specific assumption regarding the vector's contents. BTW, it declares a variable it never uses.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the problem is to find out the diameter of a tree.

> Diameter of a Tree - It is the longest path between two nodes in a
> tree.

Longest path will always occur between two leaf nodes.

Let's say, from given array you have made the tree.

Now you can use 2 DFS or BFS to do it.

> Procedure:
>
> 1. Start BFS from a random node (let's say we run from root node) and
>    find out the farthest node from it. Let the farthest node be X. It is
>    clear that X will always be a leaf node.
> 2. Now if we start BFS from X and check the farthest node from it (like
>    we did previously), we will get the diameter of the tree.

Sample code:

```
#define MAX 40001

vector<int> adj[MAX];
int dist[MAX];
int totalNode;

pair<int, int> _bfs(int startingNode) {
    for(int i=0; i <= totalNode; i++) {
        dist[i] = 0;
    }

    dist[startingNode] = 1;
    int maxDistance = 0, farthestNode;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(startingNode);

    while(!q.empty()) {
        int currNode = q.front();
        q.pop();

        int sz = adj[currNode].size();
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            int nextNode = adj[currNode][i];

            if(dist[nextNode] == 0) {
                dist[nextNode] = dist[currNode] + 1;
                q.push(nextNode);

                if(dist[nextNode] > maxDistance) {
                    maxDistance = dist[nextNode], farthestNode = nextNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {farthestNode, maxDistance};
}
int _getDiameter(int &rootNode) {
    // Running the first BFS from the root node (as explained in the procedue 1)
    pair<int, int> pii = _bfs(rootNode);

    // Running the second BFS from the furthest node we've found after running first BFS (as explained in the procedure 2)
    pair<int, int> pii2 = _bfs(pii.first);

    return pii2.second;
}
int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A) {
    totalNode = A.size();
    int rootNode;

    if(totalNode == 1) return 0;
    if(totalNode == 2) return 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < totalNode; i++) adj[i].clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < totalNode; i++) {
        int n = A[i];
        if(n == -1) rootNode = i;
        else adj[i].push_back(n), adj[n].push_back(i);
    }

    return _getDiameter(rootNode) - 1;
}
```

Reference:

[Diameter of a tree using DFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-tree-using-dfs/)

[Finding Diameter of a Tree using DFS with proof](https://iq.opengenus.org/diameter-of-tree-using-dfs/)

Comment: Are you suggesting that if I start from any leaf node and run BFS/DFS once it will provide me with the diameter of the tree???

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Nope, you've been clearly told you'd need to run the search twice.

Comment: @Anonymous668890 I've added comment in my code. Please read the procedure again from beginning, then see the code. According to the mentioned procedure, you'll have to run 2 BFS or DFS to get the diameter of the tree.

Comment: This: _'Longest path will always occur between two leaf nodes.'_ is not true.

Comment: ......at least not in a 'tree' understood as data structure in programming (a rooted DAG). :)